# Strange behavior DateInterval in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have this code:

```
$i1 = DateInterval::createFromDateString('10 minutes');
$i2 = DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes');
var_dump($i1 > $i2);
var_dump($i1 > $i2);
var_dump($i1);
var_dump($i1 > $i2);
var_dump($i1 > $i2);
```

And this output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {
  ...
}
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Is it a php bug?
Help me to understand the reason for this behavior

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547855/are-php-dateinterval-comparable-like-datetime?rq=1. Notably the part in the answer where it says "doing a var dump changes the outcome".